# ROC curve in R using ROCR package

Tags: r, roc

Can someone explain me please how to plot a ROC curve with ROCR.
I know that I should first run:

```
prediction(predictions, labels, label.ordering = NULL)
```

and then:

```
performance(prediction.obj, measure, x.measure="cutoff", ...)
```

I am just not clear what is meant with prediction and labels. I created a model with ctree and cforest and I want the ROC curve for both of them to compare it in the end. In my case the class attribute is y_n, which I suppose should be used for the labels. But what about the predictions? Here are the steps of what I do (dataset name= bank_part):

```
pred<-cforest(y_n~.,bank_part)
tablebank<-table(predict(pred),bank_part$y_n)
prediction(tablebank, bank_part$y_n)
```

After running the last line I get this error:

```
Error in prediction(tablebank, bank_part$y_n) : 
Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels.
```

Thanks in advance!

Here's another example: I have the training dataset(bank_training) and testing dataset(bank_testing) and I ran a randomForest as below:

```
bankrf<-randomForest(y~., bank_training, mtry=4, ntree=2,    
keep.forest=TRUE,importance=TRUE) 
bankrf.pred<-predict(bankrf, bank_testing, type='response')
```

Now the bankrf.pred is a factor object with labels c=("0", "1"). Still, I don't know how to plot ROC, cause I get stuck to the prediction part. Here's what I do

```
library(ROCR) 
pred<-prediction(bankrf.pred$y, bank_testing$c(0,1)
```

But this is still incorrect, cause I get the error message

```
Error in bankrf.pred$y_n : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: If you provided a full blown, self-contained example, you might get a wider audience that can help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for some tips on how to do that.

Answer (score 25):

The predictions are your continuous predictions of the classification, the labels are the binary truth for each variable.

So something like the following should work:

```
> pred <- prediction(c(0.1,.5,.3,.8,.9,.4,.9,.5), c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1))
> perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")
> plot(perf)
```

to generate an ROC.

EDIT: It may be helpful for you to include the sample reproducible code in the question (I'm having a hard time intepreting your comment).

There's no new code here, but... here's a function I use quite often for plotting an ROC:

```
 plotROC <- function(truth, predicted, ...){
   pred <- prediction(abs(predicted), truth)    
   perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")

   plot(perf, ...)
}
```

Comment: [edit]I still don't get it. Here's another example: I have the training dataset(bank_training) and testing dataset(bank_testing) and I ran a randomForest as below:

    bankrf<-randomForest(y~., bank_training, mtry=4, ntree=2,  

    keep.forest=TRUE,importance=TRUE)         
    bankrf.pred<-predict(bankrf, bank_testing)
    library(ROCR)
    pred<-prediction(bankrf.pred$y, bank_testing$y)

But this is still incorrect, cause I get the error message that there's an error in the format of prediction.

Answer (score 7):

Like @Jeff said, your predictions need to be continuous for `ROCR`'s `prediction` function. `require(randomForest); ?predict.randomForest` shows that, by default, `predict.randomForest` returns a prediction on the original scale (class labels, in classification), whereas `predict.randomForest(..., type = 'prob')` returns probabilities of each class. So:

```
require(ROCR)
data(iris)
iris$setosa <- factor(1*(iris$Species == 'setosa'))
iris.rf <- randomForest(setosa ~ ., data=iris[,-5])
summary(predict(iris.rf, iris[,-5]))
summary(iris.preds <- predict(iris.rf, iris[,-5], type = 'prob'))
preds <- iris.preds[,2]
plot(performance(prediction(preds, iris$setosa), 'tpr', 'fpr'))
```

gives you what you want. Different classification packages require different commands for getting predicted probabilities -- sometimes it's `predict(..., type='probs')`, `predict(..., type='prob')[,2]`, etc., so just check out the help files for each function you're calling.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can do it:

have our data in a csv file,("data_file.csv") but you may need to give the full path here. In that file have the column headers, which here I will use
 "default_flag", "var1", "var2", "var3", where default_flag is 0 or 1 and the other variables have any value. 
R code:

```
rm(list=ls())
df <- read.csv("data_file.csv") #use the full path if needed
mylogit <- glm(default_flag ~  var1 + var2 + var3, family = "binomial" , data = df)

summary(mylogit)
library(ROCR)

df$score<-predict.glm(mylogit, type="response" )
pred<-prediction(df$score,df$default_flag)
perf<-performance(pred,"tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf)
auc<- performance(pred,"auc")
auc
```

Note that df$score will give you the probability of default. 
In case you want to use this logit (same regression coefficients) to test in another data df2 set for cross validation, use

```
df2 <- read.csv("data_file2.csv")

df2$score<-predict.glm(mylogit,newdata=df2, type="response" )

pred<-prediction(df2$score,df2$default_flag)
perf<-performance(pred,"tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf)
auc<- performance(pred,"auc")
auc
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, as pointed out by others, prediction in ROCR expects numerical values. If you are inserting predictions from `randomForest` (as the first argument into prediction in ROCR), that prediction needs to be generated by `type='prob'` instead of `type='response'`, which is the default. Alternatively, you could take `type='response'` results and convert to numerical (that is, if your responses are, say 0/1). But when you plot that, ROCR generates a single meaningful point on ROC curve. For having many points on your ROC curve, you really need the probability associated with each prediction - i.e. use `type='prob'` in generating predictions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you would like to run the prediction function on multiple runs for example for cross-validatation.

In this case for prediction(predictions, labels, label.ordering = NULL) function the class of "predictions" and "labels" variables should be list or matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
library(ROCR)
pred<-ROCR::prediction(bankrf.pred$y, bank_testing$c(0,1)
```

The function prediction is present is many packages. You should explicitly specify(ROCR::) to use the one in ROCR. This one worked for me.